# Inserir marginRight numa TextView pelo código Java

Tags: android, textview

Eu fiz o seguinte código para inserir *TextViews* em um *LinearLayout* já definido.

```
public void inserirLacunas(){
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutLetras);

    for(int i = 0; i < palavraCerta.length(); i++){
        TextView lacuna = new TextView(this);
        lacuna.setText("_");
        lacuna.setTextSize(40);
        ll.addView(lacuna);
    }
}
```

Minha dúvida é: como eu posso botar um `marginRight` na *TextView* lacuna, para que, na hora que o código for executado, não fique com as *TextViews* muito próximas uma das outras?

> palavraCerta é outra variável criada anteriormente no código, que não interessa nessa dúvida

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terá de criar um objecto do tipo *LinearLayout.LayoutParams*, indicar os parâmetros e atribui-lo ao *TextView*:

```
public void inserirLacunas(){
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutLetras);

    for(int i = 0; i < palavraCerta.length(); i++){
        TextView lacuna = new TextView(this);
        lacuna.setText("_");
        lacuna.setTextSize(40);

        //Ciar parâmetros 
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = 
               new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        //Definir as margens
        params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom)//Introduza os valores pretendidos.
        //Atribuir os parâmetros ao TextView
        lacuna.setLayoutParams(params);
        ll.addView(lacuna);
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual deve ser a importação para "LayoutParams"?

Comment: Depende, o melhor é alterar para `LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`